# MySQL connect on Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vagrant, laravel-5

Can't run `artisan migrate`. This error appear:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Here is a partial of my .env file:

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=scotchbox
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

Running `mysqladmin -u root -p status` on SSH return this:

> Uptime: 1308  Threads: 3  Questions: 131  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 48  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 41  Queries per second avg: 0.100

If I change `DB_PASSWORD` to '', the system cannot find the table:

> [PDOException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'scotchbox'

Here is the MySQL Workbench screen confirm the connection:

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**

Now, I'm trying using homestead. But the error is the same:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Are you sure you have a database named `scotchbox` ?

Comment: do `php artisan cache:clear`  and try again.

Comment: @JilsonThomas Yes. I cant connect using MySQL Workbench.

Comment: @JilsonThomas already did this.

Comment: In your error, it says: `Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' `.  Is your database.php file configured correctly? You put your username as root in .env file and laravel reads homestead

Comment: @JilsonThomas Sorry. I edit the error.

Comment: `(using password: YES)` this means you've given a password. But you said there is no password.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I try with and without password. Without password, the system can't find the table.

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the MySQL Workbench when its logged in ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas Here is.

Comment: @JilsonThomas I don't known if matters, but I'm running Laravel with Vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Laravel's default credentials:

```
Username: homestead
Password: secret
```

Once you are able to connect successfully, create a new user in the database with the desired username and password.

Let me know if that helped!

Comment: just change the error:  Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: I'm not using homestead. Instead that, I'm using a Vagrant box called Scotchbox.

Comment: Do you have a ssh key? or can you connect freely providing just username/password to your vagrant box?

Comment: I just type ```vagrant ssh``` to access.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Database connection in the .env file. The .env file should be in the your project root.